# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file

Tags: php

I'm just working on a system to inject forms into my database, but it didn't work.

This is my code:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

$con = mysql_connect("CENSORED","PRIVATE","REALLY PRIVATE");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("EVEN MORE PRIVATE", $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO data (email, user)
VALUES
('$_POST[email]','$_POST[username]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "1 record added";

mysql_close($con);

?>
```

I'm creating an invite system, just FYI.

Comment: I recommend working in an editor with syntax highlighting, as these kind of errors are then _very_ visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first curly bracket currently has no closing curly bracket.
You forgot a closing curly bracket somewhere in your code...probably at the end of the code you posted.

Replace:

```
mysql_close($con);

?>
```

With:

```
mysql_close($con);
}
?>
```

Comment: \*facepalm-to-self*

EDIT: This worked! Now I only need to figure out what I did wrong when filling in the username/password...

Answer (score 0):

Quotes are missing in

```
$con = mysql_connect("CENSORED,"PRIVATE","REALLY PRIVATE");
```

chage to :

```
$con = mysql_connect("CENSORED","PRIVATE","REALLY PRIVATE");
```

**NOTE :**
 
1. mysql_* functions are deprecated use mysqli_* or PDO
2. Your query is vulnerable to sql injection, make it seccure.

Answer (score 0):

```
$con = mysql_connect("CENSORED,"PRIVATE","REALLY PRIVATE");
```

change to

```
$con = mysql_connect("CENSORED","PRIVATE","REALLY PRIVATE");
```